# Slumdog millionaire (12)

Tags: knowledge

My Indian friend Jamal recently participated in the well-known TV quiz
show ***[Who wants to be a millionaire?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who_Wants_to_Be_a_Millionaire)***. You might have heard or read about Jamal's spectacular success; the media reported on it extensively.

Here is what Jamal told us about the 125.000 Euro question:

> Unfortunately the next question brought back sad memories of my high school
>   years. Prem Kumar gave us a big smile, and it was absolutely clear that he
>   had no idea what the question was about.
>
> B was the only answer that was not on, but I was pretty sure that it was one.
>   And Superman's was one also, and that eliminated C.  That left me with
>   A and D.  I didn't know one from the other.  Both had five letters, both
>   started with a consonant, and both starting consonants were pretty common
>   consonants.  Cleverly I then decided to use my 50/50 lifeline.  I hoped
>   that A or D would be eliminated.  Prem asked the computer to take away
>   two wrong answers, and answers C and D disappeared.  So I chose A. I was
>   excited to find out that I was correct!

***What was the 125.000 Euro question?

What were the four possible answers A, B, C, D?***

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From your description, I think the question and answers are:

> Which one of these is NOT a noble gas?                                           A. Boron, B. Helium, C. Krypton, D. Radon

B was the only answer that was not on, but I was pretty sure that it was one.

> This refers to the common 'on' ending to noble gas names, helium is an exception.

And Superman's was one also, and that eliminated C.

> Superman's home planet is Krypton

I think the rest doesn't require a description.

Comment: Nice answer, this has to be it!

Comment: I was also thinking this, but couldn't quite put it all together. Looks good!